# validating form before it submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**WHAT IM DOING** 
I'm using jquery to validate form before it is send to server. 
I'm validating every input, and if any of them return false i call `event.preventDefault()` and show the errors.(if it returns true I do nothing...) 
**THE PROBLEM** 
It was working fine, the script always run before the form send itself, but now I'm validating email, using `ajax` -  checking if email isnt already in db or if the domain exists... but when the `ajax` starts, the the form wont wait until its finished and sends itself before the `ajax` finish and the input validates.

**SOME SOLUTIONS MAYBE** 
I could call `event.preventDefault()` and after the validation is completed and it returns true I could try to undo the `preventDefault` perhabs by `unbind` and then `submit` through jquery submit the form again. 
 
Or perhabs I could do `onsubmit="checkInputs();"` and it should wait until it returns true or false...

**Solution** - Adapted from the accepted answer by user [Mirage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3197998/mirage)

```
function validate(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://google.nl',
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: {test:'request'},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });    
    return data; // important
}
```

Comment: ajax is asynchronous, try to make it syncronous by adding async: false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add

```
async: false
```

example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.nl',
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: {test:'request'},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: this worked for me, but only when i have `return value;` after ajax..., without it it still triiger the form...

Comment: Good to hear that you fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

you want:

```
onsubmit="checkInputs(); return false;"
```

Then you would grab the form e.g:

```
var frm = document.getElementById("myfrm");
frm.submit();
```

You would place the above in the else condition of your validation logic. Hope this helps.

Comment: The above is the non jquery logic

Comment: be aware that you'll end up in a validation loop here, as when you submit the form programatically it'll fall into the onsubmit handler again.

Comment: That's how i read the question that all input must be validated before submitting. The return false will validate and only if an eventual true condition then it will submit the form.

Comment: Sorry I was confused: when using jquery (`trigger('submit')`) it'll fall into the onsubmit handler again, while when you submit the form like above, it ignores the handler altogether. So this will indeed post the form, despite of the `return false;` in the handler (unless you return anything or just do not submit the form programatically)

Comment: Its got me thinking now that you either need to leave the button as a submit button or set it as a button with the onsubmit logic including return false. Its one of these combinations. The reason that you would place it in an else condition or corresponding function in jquery is that it will only get there and submit a form if all fields are valid.

Comment: Why would you need to remove the validation if your submitting the form as the next page load the validation won't be there.

Comment: Well, if you use jQuery and you trigger the submit event (`$('#myform').trigger('submit');`), the attached handler will execute once again. And if you're handler has detected that the values are fine, it'll trigger the submit event, which will execute your handler again. This will end up in a loop. But if you remove the attached handler, it will NOT validate again but just post the form, and it'll be up to the server. But this only happens if you attach and trigger event handlers with jquery. If you do it your way, using pure JS, it ignores the handler in the `onsubmit="..."` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Your script flow should be something like this:

1. Bind onsubmit handler
2. Send vars to server with ajax
3. Check results

   1. When validates: remove handler and post form
   2. When false: show error messages and start over again.

And in code:

```
var handleValidationResponse = function(data) {
    if(data.errors != 0) {
        alert('Sorry my dear user, but you made a mistake');
        return false;
    }
    // aight, so it's all fine
    $('#myForm').off('submit').trigger('submit'); // unbind custom submit handler and post the form
};

$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var serializedFormData = $this.serializeArray();
    $.post($this.attr('action'), serializedFormData, function(data) {
        handleValidationResponse(data);
    });
});
```

That should be it!